# Relative url automatic rewrite in asp.net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-rewriting, relative-path

ASP.net MVC 2 does rewrite all your relative urls in the `<link>` tag to the full relative path, which is good but it only works for URLs written in the `<link>` tag only, not `<script>` tags or any other elements.

1. Create an MVC 2 web application
2. create any controller and a view for it
3. inside the view create a `<link>` tag like this `<link href="test.xml" type="text/css"/>`
4. run your application, navigate to the view you created and then view source

you will find that MVC has rewritten your url in  tag to full url like:

```
<link href="../Views/Home/Text.xml" type="text/css" />
```

i know that this file is in the Views folder and can't be viewed due to the web.config file that blocks any requests to files there, but thats not my problem

How can i get MVC to rewrite all urls not only in the `<link>` tage ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your `<head>` tag has a `runat="server"` attribute (a nasty heritage from WebForms). Remove it and no rewrites will happen. Also instead of:

```
<link href="test.css" type="text/css" />
```

you should always use Url helpers when dealing with urls:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/test.css") %>" type="text/css" />
```

You should not leave automatic rewrites to happen, always use `Url.Content` for linking static resources.

Comment: i see, but i want the rewrite to happen but not only for the <link> tag, for all tags like <script>, thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, that's why you should always use `Url.Content` as in my example in order to specify urls. That's the correct way to set urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. And for dynamic urls linking to controller actions you should use the corresponding html helpers: `Html.ActionLink`, `Html.BeginForm`, ...

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, i know about Url.Content but i cant use it coz i dnt know where my folder will be placed, its a kind of a folder you upload to the server and its up to server where it should be saved. i only want to use relative URLs like what happens in the <link> tag.

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, I don't understand. Is this folder part of the web application root or it could be anywhere on the server? If it can be anywhere don't expect client browsers to be able to access it. It needs to be inside your server root and if it is simply use `Url.Content("~/uploads")` in order to get the correct relative path to this folder no matter where and how the application is hosted.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Yes its a part of the web application root, but your folder might be renamed when its uploaded to the server, so you cant know the exact path

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, I don't understand how a folder can be renamed. Isn't you that gave name to the folder? Who renames it?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes, i create a folder and i give it a name, i put files in this folder and web forms with relative urls, i then compress this folder and upload the compressed file to the server, then my web application in the server extract this zipped file but with diffrent name, also extracted in a folder that i don't know its full path, you see ?

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, no I don't understand. Why uncompressing would change a folder name?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, coz it might be duplicated alot of people upload folders, its a part of an enterprise application

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, if you don't know the folder name I don't see how you will create a link to it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, all my files will be in the same folder, relative paths should work, <link href="test.xml" /> despite the folder name, test.xml should work coz its inside the same folder where the page that links to it.

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, in MVC the pages are inside the `~/Views` folder and urls are based on the current Controller Action contrary to classic web forms. I think there is something wrong in your design.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, nothing wrong with my design, as i'v mentioned before its an enterprise application that has its own ControllerFactory and WebFormViewEngine and diffrent routes, in my application views can be outside the views folder but we are getting far from the problem ?

Comment: @Ahmed Galal, I am afraid I don't really understand the problem. Hopefully someone does and will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you have already tried something like this

```
<head runat="server">
 <link href="test.xml" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="<%= ((WebFormView)this.ViewContext.View).ViewPath.Substring(1, 
  ((WebFormView)this.ViewContext.View).ViewPath.LastIndexOf('/')) %>test1.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

renders html as

```
<head>
 <link href="Views/Shared/test.xml" type="text/css" />
 <script src="/Views/Home/test1.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: thats works, however i was looking for a way that makes automatic url rewrite happens as it happens in the <link> tag, thanks for ur help